# Eclipse 4.5.1 jpa 2.1 facet error

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, jpa

My problem is similar to the one described in [eclipse 4.3 EE facet jpa 2.0 build error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18320303/eclipse-4-3-ee-facet-jpa-2-0-build-error) .. EXCEPT I'm using a newly installed version of Eclipse Mars Java EE 4.5.1 .. AND .. I can't create a JPA 2.1 project right-clicking the project / 'Properties' / 'Project facet' ... The project itself is a Maven project that has dependencies: (i) hibernate-jpa-2.1-api/1.0.0.Final, (ii) hibernate-core/5.0.7.Final, and (iii) hibernate-entitymanager/5.0.7.Final. Interestingly, selecting JPA 2.0 in the facet doesn't generate an error, but JPA 2.1 does.

Comment: And what is the current error ?

Comment: @JorgeCampos error is a null pointer exception. Solved this by creating a new workspace .. BUT .. JavaEE still performs erratically. "Erratic" here means the JPA tools will allow something at time #1, and then later start throwing all sorts of false positives. The project consists of JPA entity models. Some models show errors while others don't where they have the exact same configuration. I'm convinced the problem relates to using Maven/Eclipse/JPA together, ... this is NOT a good fit. I've never encountered anything so brittle and fickle.